# How does argmax works for Three Dimensional array?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensor

```
    x=tf.constant ([
      [[1,2,3],
       [4,5,6]],
       [[7,8,9],
       [10,11,12]],
       [[13,14,15],
       [16,17,18]]])
    #print(x)
    print(tf.math.argmax(x,axis=0))
```

Result:

```
tf.Tensor(
         [[2 2 2]
          [2 2 2]], shape=(2, 3), dtype=int64)
```

How does argmax() works for 3D-Arrays??
please someone help!!!

Comment: Take a look at [`tf.math.argmax` documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/argmax)

Answer (score 1):

The result at (0,0) gives you the index (along axis=0) with the highest number. 
So here you compare 1, 7 and 13. Since 13 is the largest number, the result at (0,0) = 2
For the result at (0,1) you compare 2, 8 and 14 and so on...

Answer (score 0):

### Documented Defentions

From **TF** documentation you can find the following definition:

> Returns the index with the largest value across axes of a tensor.

As the argmax is a common function among libraries and frameworks that do some sort of matrix manipulation, we can take a look at documents from *numpy* or even *PyTourch* to get a better insight:

###### Numpy

> Returns the indices of the maximum values along an axis.
> **Returns:** array of indices into the array. It has the same shape as a.shape with the dimension along axis removed.

###### PyTorch

> Returns the indices of the maximum values of a tensor across a dimension.

From these, we can understand that argmax function calculates some maximum values in a specific way and returns their arguments. But how?

### Unformal Definition

Suppose you have an array with 2 dimensions *i* and *j* and you want to calculate the maximum value in this array. You can find **3** useful methods of finding a sort of maximum value:

1. Find a maximum value among all elements ( `axis = -1` ).
2. Find a maximum value among all rows ( `axis = 0` ).
3. Find a maximum value among all columns ( `axis = 1` ).

Generalizing the previous, for an array with **N** dimension, we can find a maximum value looking from each **N** dimension **plus one** other way of looking at the array as a whole. That is **N+1** way (listing in programming from `(axis = -1)` to `(axis = N-1)`).

### Visuals

Looking at some examples, the case for **1-dimensional** array is pretty clear.
[image]
Simply compare every element and return the argument of the maximum element.

###### 2-Dimensions

The case for `(axis = -1)` is clear. As for other ones, each argmax should return a **new array** with sizes respective to the remaining dimensions. For example, if the argmax is calculated among *columns*, then the return size will be of the size of *number of columns* (maximum for each column).

###### Row argmax `(axis = 0)`:

Notice that the size of the returned array is the same as the number of rows.
[image]

###### Column argmax `(axis = 1)`:

Notice that the size of the returned array is the same as the number of columns.
[image]

###### 3-Dimensions

As for the case of 3-Dimensions, the pattern should be clear by now. Visualization is much more complicated so I removed the values and only color-coded the elements that would be compared to each other in order to calculate argmax for each axis.

###### D1 argmax `(axis = 0)`:

[image]

###### D2 argmax `(axis = 1)`:

[image]

###### D3 argmax `(axis = 2)`:

[image]